# When to assign two attribute set in Magento?

Tags: magento, attributes, magento-1.7

I have two websites in a single magento installation.

I want to have some products that should be shown in both the websites.

Price and other things will be different for both the websites.

In Website1 I have to use some custom attributes but in Website2 those custom attributes are not required.

> Should I create two Attribute set for Individual Website specific
>   products?
>
> Will it create any problem in maintaining the products as some
>   products will be used in both the websites ?

Comment: provide more information. like, currency is same or not? product price should be same for both or not? warehouse is same for both the websites or not? etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento provides options for this by default.

- You can set to which websites a product is applied.
- You can modify product information on multiple levels (website, store-view).

So probably not a problem if you use the same product and manage it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

**Product entities have exactly one attribute set in the application**; it is not possible to define multiple attribute sets for products. Attributes can be defined as having website scope which will allow you to set values for those attributes at the website level. However, attributes metadata (e.g. "Visible on Product View Page on Front-end", "Use In Layered Navigation", etc.) are evaluated globally. Configurable options also must be global, but as these option values should represent stock items, that should not be a concern.

Products already require active association with websites, and product pricing can be configured as either Global or Website (see `System > Configuration > Catalog > Price > Catalog Price Scope`), so you are good to go with these two requirements.